# How to compile Sass with Polymer using Gulp?

Tags: sass, gulp, polymer-2.x

I have a problem with Polymer and Sass. When I create elements and I style them with Sass [for time saving] it only compiles the first one correctly.

Here is my file structure:

[image: file Structure]

My HTML element:

```
<dom-module id='footer-view'>
    <template>
        <style>
        /*Style goes here*/
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

And above elements so many example header-view.html

And when I run my Gulp it's compiled and works but multiple files are not compiling.

Here is my Gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    // sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    min = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    tar = require('gulp-tar'),
    gzip = require('gulp-gzip'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    util = require('gulp-util'),
    nodeSass = require('node-sass'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    map = require('map-stream'),
    buildPath = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/src/ui/',
    buildSrcPath = path.join(buildPath);

var PATH_JS_SRC = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/js/',
    PATH_CSS_SRC = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/src/scss/',
    PATH_DIST = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/',
    srcPath = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/src/';


gulp.task('inject', function() {
    return gulp.src([srcPath + 'css/*.html'])
        .pipe(map(function(file, cb) {
            var injectString = '/*Style goes here*/';
            // convert file buffer into a string
            var contents = file.contents.toString();
            if (contents.indexOf(injectString) >= 0) {
                //Getting scss
                var scssFile = file.path.replace(/\.html$/i, '.scss');
                fs.readFile(scssFile, function(err, data) {
                    if (!err && data) {
                        nodeSass.render({
                            data: data.toString(),
                            includePaths: [path.join(srcPath, ' ')],
                            outputStyle: 'compressed'
                        }, function(err, compiledScss) {
                            if (!err && compiledScss) {
                                file.contents = new Buffer(contents.replace(injectString, compiledScss.css.toString()), 'binary');
                            }
                            return cb(null, file);
                        });
                    }
                    return cb(null, file);
                });
            } else {
                // continue
                return cb(null, file);
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(buildSrcPath, '')));
});
```

And the compiled result:

[image: Compiled Results]

And the failed result:
[image: Failed]

But if I just choose one HTML and compile it as

```
return gulp.src([srcPath + 'css/footer-css.html'])
```

It gives me this:

[image: Success]

Comment: I would start by using fs.readFileSync instead of fs.readFile which is obviously asynchronous and probably causing you problems.